# Using sed, how can I append a string to lines that contain a pattern and don't already have the string appended?

Tags: sed

Eq.
I have file with the following contents

```
ERR001 just some random text
ERR002 blah blah blah
ERR001 again some text //IGNORE
ERR001 blah blahblah blah blah
ERR002 abc def ghi
```

I to write a sed command that append //IGNORE to all line that have ERR001 but do not already have //IGNORE appended. So the sed command should give the below output for the above file

```
ERR001 just some random text //IGNORE
ERR002 blah blah blah
ERR001 again some text //IGNORE
ERR001 blah blahblah blah blah //IGNORE
ERR002 abc def ghi
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. The goal is that you add some code of your own to your question to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**`sed`** solution:

```
sed '/\/\/IGNORE$/! s/^ERR001 .*/& \/\/IGNORE/' inputfile
```

- `/\/\/IGNORE$/!` - negated matching, ensures that line is not ended with `//IGNORE` (`!` - negation sign)
- `s/^ERR001 .*/& \/\/IGNORE/` - substitute a line that started with `ERR001`

The output:

```
ERR001 just some random text //IGNORE
ERR002 blah blah blah
ERR001 again some text //IGNORE
ERR001 blah blahblah blah blah //IGNORE
ERR002 abc def ghi
```

Comment: An alternative notation would be: `sed '\|//IGNORE$|! s|^ERR001 .*|& //IGNORE|' inputfile`